# I am unable to access the list element

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, index-error

this might be stupid question but after executing this code it is giving this error

```
pl.append(a[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

code-

```
import re

f=open("finetuning.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

pl=[]
discriminator=[]




for line in lines:
    a = re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',line)
    pl.append(a[0])
    discriminator.append(a[1])




print(pl,discriminator)
```

after executing this code it is giving this error-

Comment: Well, think about it: if the index `0` is out of range, how many elements could there be? Did you try checking the value of `a`? Did you try checking the value of `line`?

Comment: yes after printing a line it has ```['50', '100000', '0.0849', '1.8333'] ``` this value

Comment: But does it have output for every line?

Comment: yes, all lines are getting printed..with 4 values

Comment: There might be a blank line in the end of your file, for which this code will throw. Are you that your file doesn't end with `\n`?

Comment: @Gabip thanks man.. that was the issue..there were 2 blank lines at the end of a file..

Comment: You may want to find out soon what Python version you are using. Python 2.7 is officially dead.

Comment: @usr2564301 i know that, but to be honest, i was not getting enough tags to put.. I am really sorry, won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there was no match in the string to the regular expression, so a Is an empty list. If you want to access the list at index 0 or 1 you must check if the list is long enough.

```
import re

f=open("finetuning.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

pl=[]
discriminator=[]




for line in lines:
    a = re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',line)
    if len(a) >= 0:
        pl.append(a[0])
    if len(a) >= 1:
        discriminator.append(a[1])




print(pl,discriminator)
```

Comment: yes it is long enough.. i also thought the same..but only printing a line is giving me this o/p - ``` ['50', '100000', '0.0849', '1.8333']```

Comment: what is the output when you print a for each line in the file?

Comment: when i print ```a``` the o/p is - ```['50', '100000', '0.0849', '1.8333']``` there are such 1988 lines

Comment: List index out of range means that your list is too short with 2000 line you won't notice one empty list. Put a try catch block and when you catch an exeption print a and see the output.

Comment: actually, there were 2 blank lines at the end of the file..i got rid of those and now it is not showing error..still thanks for suggesting me this.. i ll definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: You should still add the if. It's good prctice and mostly you want your code to be able to handle the case where someone edits the file, or you get a new file that might contains blank lines.